# Twitter API status update don't work as cron

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

the following code **works fine by executing in the browser**, but as **a cron it doesn't work** without any error message...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

// Twitter-StatusUpdate
$my_message = "test";
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "xyz",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxx",
    'consumer_key' => "yyy",
    'consumer_secret' => "zzz"
);
$url_media = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$requestMethod = "POST";

// Tweet 
$tweetmsg = $my_message;
$twimg = "picture.jpg"; //not active
    $postfields = array(
        'status' => $tweetmsg,
        'media[]' => '@' . $twimg   //not active
    );
    try {
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$twitter->buildOauth($url_media, $requestMethod)
  ->setPostfields($postfields)
  ->performRequest();

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
```

(you can ignore the image-part)

Any ideas why this don't work as a cronjob?

Thanks in advance!

Tom

Comment: It usually helps to indicate what language you're using, by tagging your question appropriately.  Also, maybe show your crontab line?  Finally *"doesn't work without any error message"* - does this mean you get an error message? Or you don't?

Comment: Hey Jonathon! Sorry, I edited it. I use php only. The cron is executing correctly, I've checked this, but the twitter part doesn't work in cron-mode. By executing the .php in my browser the twitter-part works correctly.

Comment: there is NO error message

Answer (score 0):

With the given information - can you use the absolute location of the php file - TwitterAPIExchange.php in the require statement.

Comment: you mean by using the absolute path of TwitterAPIExchange.php in the script? in an other cron (which just read the number of followers) it works fine.